# Import Library from tensorflow as tf

Tags: tensorflow, libraries

How to import library in latest version of tensorflow
**from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import MaxPooling2D** in the program
[enter image description here][1]

Error in the Code
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOVZk.png

Comment: Why would max pooling be in the optimizers module??

Comment: are you saying that there is no need to use optimzer?

Comment: I am saying that `MaxPool2D` lives in the `layers` module, not the `optimizers` module, so you cannot import `MaxPool2D` from `optimizers`. Please familiarize yourself with [the Keras API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras).

Comment: Thanks Bro I solve the problem by your help

Comment: Can you tell me where we have to define errors? 
            NameError: name 'classifier' is not defined  https://www.facebook.com/messenger_media/?thread_id=100001869036878&attachment_id=312824903774689&message_id=mid.%24cAAAABmeNOrJ-mhd36l4aNLglchlL

Comment: You are using classifier to make predictions. But the classifier is not defined. That is what the above error.